# Ansible did not find expected key syntax error

Tags: ansible

I want to give change permission for myuser on windows_host, but I can't manage to make the code to be working. The error code is `ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML. did not find expected key` and points at `- name` 
I have tried almost all configutarions (except for working one). Can you spot the syntax error?

```
---
- hosts: windows_host
  - name: share permission 
    ansible.windows.win_share:
      name: test
      path: "C:\test"
      change: myuser
```

Comment: You should include the error message you received, not ask people to play "guess the syntax error".

Answer (score 1):

That is not valid YAML, and also not a valid playbook. The task list belongs under a `tasks` key:

```
- hosts: windows_host
  tasks:
    - name: share permission 
      ansible.windows.win_share:
        name: test
        path: "C:\test"
        change: myuser
```

Comment: Had this version as well. It gives ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

Comment: It's possible that you are using an old version of Ansible in which that action does not exist, or does not exist by that name. Try using the short name (`win_share`) instead of the FQCN. If you are using a version of ansible that is newer than 2.9, make sure you have the `ansible.windows` collection installed.

Comment: You should also consider upgrading to a newer version of Ansible, if you're not on at least 2.10; 2.9 has an especially extended support cycle for various reasons, but is only receiving critical security fixes.